# Find last string after delimiter: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a url with many delimiters '/'.

I want to find the string after the last delimiter. How can I write a javascript code?

for eg  if my url is

```
localhost/sample/message/invitation/create/email
```

I want to display 'email' as my output.

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) + [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var last = input.split("/").pop();
```

Simples!

Answer (score 0):

```
var url="localhost/sample/message/invitation/create/email";
  url.split("/").pop()
```

or

```
var last=$(url.split("/")).last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on a regex that matches spaces or hyphens and taking the last element

```
var lw = function(v) {
  return (""+v).replace(/[\s-]+$/,'').split(/[\s-]/).pop();
};
lw('This is a test.'); // returns 'test.'
lw('localhost/sample/message/invitation/create/email,'); // returns 'email,'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usng simple regex

```
var str = "localhost/sample/message/invitation/create/email";
var last = str.match(/[^/]*$/)[0]";
```

Above regex return all character after last "/"